# Footnote isn't showing up

Tags: footnotes, margins, article

I believe my margins are conflicting with my footnote, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=7.5in]{geometry}

% Some definitions
\textheight=10in
\pagestyle{fancy}
\raggedright
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }

\newcommand{\contact}[3]{
\vspace*{5pt}
\begin{center}
{\huge \scshape {#1}}\\
\vspace{3pt}
#2 
\vspace{2pt}
#3
\end{center}
\vspace*{-8pt}
}
% End of definitions


\begin{document}
\small
\smallskip
\vspace*{-44pt}
\contact{Bla bla bla}{}    
 
Bla bla\footnote{My footnote is messed up}
 
\end{document}
```

Which returns the following result (the footnote doesn't show up at all):

[image: footnote not there]

If I comment out the line `\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=7.5in]{geometry}`, the footnote shows up but is still badly positioned:

[image: footnote there]

I really would like to keep using `\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=7.5in]{geometry}` but also have the footnote displayed correctly, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `geometry` package, you should avoid setting dimensions directly, because this package is good at handling them.

So, I suggest that you remove lines that set `\textheight`, `\hoffset` and `\footskip` in your file (`\textheight` is the main offender here; it drives the footnote way below page limit).
Instead of `\textheight` and `\hoffset` you can probably use `hmargin` and `vmargin` keys of the `\geometry` command (they set top, bottom and left, right margins, respectively), and instead of `\footskip` you can use `footskip` key (if you somehow know that you need it; otherwise it should be ok to leave it out):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=7.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{vmargin={1in,1in},hmargin={1in,1in},footskip=20pt}

% Some definitions
\pagestyle{fancy}
\raggedright
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }

\newcommand{\contact}[3]{
\vspace*{5pt}
\begin{center}
{\huge \scshape {#1}}\\
\vspace{3pt}
#2 
\vspace{2pt}
#3
\end{center}
\vspace*{-8pt}
}
% End of definitions

\begin{document}
\small
\smallskip
\vspace*{-44pt}
\contact{Bla bla bla}{}    
 
Bla bla\footnote{My footnote is messed up}
 
\end{document}
```